# Bootstrap tags input submit when i press Enter button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tags input in my form but when i type to add new tag click anywhere else assuming that the tag will be added nothing happen .. and when i press Enter button to add the tag the form get submitted i added this to my code

```
confirmKeys: [13, 32, 44]
```

It only worked with commas so when i type comma after the tag name i typed it gets added but a comma remains in the end of the text .. no problem with that but still with i type enter the form get submitted and when i click anywhere a tag doesn't get added :(

Here is my code

```
        <script>
        var citynames = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            prefetch: {
                url: '<?php echo site_url('assets/admin/js/citynames.json');?>',
                filter: function(list) {
                    return $.map(list, function(cityname) {
                    return { name: cityname }; });
                }
            }
        });

        citynames.initialize();

        $('#tagsinput').tagsinput({
            confirmKeys: [13, 32, 44],
            typeaheadjs: {
                name        : 'citynames',
                displayKey  : 'name',
                valueKey    : 'name',
                source      : citynames.ttAdapter()
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: use new css and script: https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/tree/master/dist